# в чем причина выдает исключение NullPointerException! и аргументы почему-то равны null!

Tags: java

помогите пожалуйста!! Почему при работе метода PreparedStatement createInsertStatement(Connection connection, Session entity) в entity film и hall равны null???[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя при создании Session аргументы были не null!!!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public class Session extends Entity<Integer> {
Film film;
Hall hall;
public int price;
public Session() {
}
public Session(Film film, Hall hall, int price) {
    this.film = film;
    this.hall = hall;
    this.price = price;
}
public class SessionDto extends Entity<Integer> {
FilmDto filmDto;
HallDto hallDto;
public int price;
public SessionDto() {
}
public SessionDto(FilmDto filmDto, HallDto hallDto, int price) {
    this.filmDto = filmDto;
    this.hallDto = hallDto;
    this.price = price;
}



 public class SessionDaoImpl extends CrudDAO<Session> {
private static final String SESSION_UPDATE = "UPDATE session SET film_id=?,hall_id=?,price=? WHERE id=?";
private static final String SESSION_INSERT = "INSERT  INTO session (film_id, hall_id, price) VALUES (?,?,?)";
public static SessionDaoImpl cruddaoSession;
public SessionDaoImpl(Class type) {
    super(Session.class);
}
public static synchronized SessionDaoImpl getInstance() {
    if (cruddaoSession == null) {
        cruddaoSession = new SessionDaoImpl(Session.class);
    }
    return cruddaoSession;
}
@Override
protected PreparedStatement createUpdateStatement(Connection connection, Session entity) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(SESSION_UPDATE);
   ps.setString(1, entity.getFilmId());
   ps.setInt(2, entity.getHallid());        ps.setInt(3, entity.getPrice());
    ps.setInt(4, entity.getId());
    return ps;
}
@Override
protected PreparedStatement createInsertStatement(Connection connection, Session entity) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement pr = connection.prepareStatement(SESSION_INSERT, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
    pr.setString(1,entity.getFilm().getTitle());
    pr.setString(2,entity.getHall().getName());
    pr.setInt(3,entity.getPrice());
    return pr;
}
public class SessionServiceImpl implements Service<Integer,SessionDto>{
public static SessionServiceImpl sessionService;
public Dao<Integer,Session> sessionDao;
public SessionDaoImpl sessionDaoImpl;
public BeanMapper beanMapper;
public SessionServiceImpl(){
    sessionDao= DaoFactory.getInstance().getSessionDao();
    beanMapper=BeanMapper.getInstance();
    sessionDaoImpl=new SessionDaoImpl(Session.class);
}
public static synchronized SessionServiceImpl getInstsnce(){
    if (sessionService == null) {
        sessionService=new SessionServiceImpl();
   }
    return sessionService;
}
@Override
public List<SessionDto> getAll() {
    List<Session>sessions=sessionDao.getAll();
    List<SessionDto>sessionDtos=beanMapper.listMapToList(sessions, SessionDto.class);
    return sessionDtos;
}
@Override
public SessionDto getById(Integer id) {
    Session session=sessionDao.getById(id);
    SessionDto sessionDto=beanMapper.singleMapper(session, SessionDto.class);
    return sessionDto;
}
@Override
public void save(SessionDto sessionDto) {
    Session session=beanMapper.singleMapper(sessionDto,Session.class);
    sessionDao.save(session);}
public final class BeanMapper {

private static BeanMapper beanMapper = new BeanMapper();
private static Mapper mapper;

private BeanMapper() {
    mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
}

public static synchronized BeanMapper getInstance() {
    if (beanMapper == null) {
        beanMapper = new BeanMapper();
    }
    return beanMapper;
}


public static <T> T singleMapper(Object from, Class<T> toClass) {
    T map = mapper.map(from, toClass);
    return map;
}

public static <E, T> List<T> listMapToList(Iterable<E> iterable, Class<T> toClass) {

    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();

    for (E e : iterable) {
        list.add(mapper.map(e, toClass));
    }
    return list;
}
```

}

```
public class UserDTO  extends Entity<Integer>{
public String login;
public String password;
public String email;
public RoleDTO role;

public UserDTO(String login, String password, String email, RoleDTO role) {
    this.login=login;
    this.password=password;
    this.email=email;
    this.role=role;
}
public class RoleDTO extends Entity<Integer> {
public String name;

public RoleDTO(){

}
public RoleDTO(String name){
    this.name=name;
}
public class UserDaoImpl extends CrudDAO<User> {

private static final String UPDATE_USER ="UPDATE user set login=?,email=?, WHERE id=?" ;
private static final String INSERT_USER ="INSERT INTO user (login, password, email, role_id) VALUES (?,?,?,?)" ;

public static UserDaoImpl crudDao;

public UserDaoImpl(Class type) {
    super(type);
}

public static synchronized UserDaoImpl getInstance(){
    if (crudDao==null){
        crudDao=new UserDaoImpl(User.class);
    }
    return crudDao;
}
@Override
protected PreparedStatement createUpdateStatement(Connection connection, User entity) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement pr=connection.prepareStatement(UPDATE_USER);
    pr.setString(1,entity.getLogin());
    pr.setString(2,entity.getEmail());
    return pr;
}

@Override
protected PreparedStatement createInsertStatement(Connection connection, User entity) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement pr=connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_USER, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
   pr.setString(1,entity.getLogin());
   pr.setString(2,entity.getPassword());
   pr.setString(3,entity.getEmail());
   pr.setInt(4,getRoleId(entity));
    return pr;
}

private int getRoleId(User entity) {
    List<Role>roles= DaoFactory.getInstance().getRoleDao().getAll();
    int roleId=0;
    for (Role r:roles) {
        if (r.getName().equals(entity.getRole().getName())){
             roleId=r.getId();
    }
    }
    return roleId;
}

@Override
protected List<User> readAll(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {

    List<User> users=new LinkedList<>();
    User user;
    while (resultSet.next()){
        user=new User();
        user.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
        user.setLogin(resultSet.getString("login"));
        user.setPassword(resultSet.getString("password"));
        user.setEmail(resultSet.getString("email"));
        user.setRole(DaoFactory.getInstance().getRoleDao().getById(resultSet.getInt("role_id")));
        users.add(user);
    }
    return users;
}
```

}

```
public class RoleDaoImpl extends CrudDAO<Role>{

public static final String INSERT_ROLE="INSERT INTO role(name) VALUES (?)";
private static final String GET_ROLE_BY_NAME = "SELECT * FROM role WHERE name LIKE ?";
private static final String UPDATE_ROLE = "UPDATE role SET name=?, WHERE id=?";
public static RoleDaoImpl crudDao;

public RoleDaoImpl(Class type) {
    super(type);
}



public static synchronized RoleDaoImpl getInstance(){
    if (crudDao==null){
        crudDao=new RoleDaoImpl(Role.class);
    }
    return crudDao;
}

@Override
protected PreparedStatement createUpdateStatement(Connection connection, Role entity) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement ps=connection.prepareStatement(UPDATE_ROLE);
    ps.setString(1,entity.getName());
    return ps;
}

@Override
protected PreparedStatement createInsertStatement(Connection connection, Role entity) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement ps=connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_ROLE, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
    ps.setString(1,entity.getName());
    return ps;
}

@Override
protected List<Role> readAll(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
  List<Role>result=new LinkedList<>();
  Role temp =null;
  while (resultSet.next()){
      temp=new Role();
      temp.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
      temp.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
      result.add(temp);
  }

    return result;
}

public Role getRoleByName(String name){
    Connection connection=DataSource.getInstance().getConnection();
    List<Role> result=null;
    try
    {
        PreparedStatement ps=connection.prepareStatement(GET_ROLE_BY_NAME);
        ps.setString(1,name);
        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
        result=readAll(rs);
        connection.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result.get(0);
}
```

}

```
public class UserServiceImp implements Service<Integer, UserDTO> {

public static UserServiceImp userServiceImp;
public Dao<Integer, User> userDao;
public BeanMapper beanMapper;

public UserServiceImp(){
    userDao= DaoFactory.getInstance().getUserDao();
    beanMapper=BeanMapper.getInstance();
}
public static synchronized UserServiceImp getInstance(){
    if (userServiceImp==null){
        userServiceImp=new UserServiceImp();
    }
    return userServiceImp;
}

@Override
public List<UserDTO> getAll() {
    List<User> users=userDao.getAll();
    List<UserDTO> userDTOS=beanMapper.listMapToList(users,UserDTO.class);

    return userDTOS;
}

@Override
public UserDTO getById(Integer id) {
    User user=userDao.getById(id);
    UserDTO userDTO=beanMapper.singleMapper(user, UserDTO.class);
    return userDTO;
}

@Override
public void save(UserDTO userDTO) {
    User user=beanMapper.singleMapper(userDTO, User.class);
    userDao.save(user);

}
public class RoleServiceImpl implements Service<Integer, RoleDTO> {

public static RoleServiceImpl roleService;
public Dao<Integer,Role> roleDao;
public BeanMapper beanMapper;

public RoleServiceImpl(){
    roleDao= DaoFactory.getInstance().getRoleDao();
    beanMapper=BeanMapper.getInstance();

}
public static synchronized RoleServiceImpl getInstance(){
    if (roleService==null){
        roleService=new RoleServiceImpl();
    }
    return roleService;
}



@Override
public List<RoleDTO> getAll() {
    List<Role> roles=roleDao.getAll();
    List<RoleDTO> roleDTOS=beanMapper.listMapToList(roles,RoleDTO.class);

    return roleDTOS;
}

@Override
public RoleDTO getById(Integer id) {
    Role role=roleDao.getById(id);
    RoleDTO roleDTO=beanMapper.singleMapper(role, RoleDTO.class);
    return roleDTO;
}

@Override
public void save(RoleDTO roleDTO) {
    Role role=beanMapper.singleMapper(roleDTO,Role.class);
    roleDao.save(role);

}
public class DaoFactory {
private static DaoFactory instance = null;

private Dao<Integer, Movie> movieDao;
private Dao<Integer, User> userDao;
private Dao<Integer, Role> roleDao;
private Dao<Integer, Film> filmDao;
private Dao<Integer, Hall> hallDao;
private Dao<Integer, Session> sessionDao;

private DaoFactory() {
    loadDaos();
}


public static DaoFactory getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new DaoFactory();
    }
    return instance;
}

private void loadDaos() {
    if (PropertyHolder.getInstance().isInMemoryDB()) {

    } else {
        movieDao = MovieDaoImpl.getInstance();
        userDao = UserDaoImpl.getInstance();
        roleDao = RoleDaoImpl.getInstance();
        filmDao = FilmDaoImpl.getInstance();
        hallDao = HallDaoImpl.getInstance();
        sessionDao = SessionDaoImpl.getInstance();
    }
}

public Dao<Integer, Movie> getMovieDao() {
    return movieDao;
}

public Dao<Integer, User> getUserDao() {
    return userDao;
}

public Dao<Integer, Role> getRoleDao() {
    return roleDao;
}

public Dao<Integer, Film> getFilmDao() {
    return filmDao;
}

public Dao<Integer, Hall> getHallDao() {
    return hallDao;
}

public Dao<Integer, Session> getSessionDao() {
    return sessionDao;
}

public void setMovieDao(Dao<Integer, Movie> movieDao) {
    this.movieDao = movieDao;
}
```

}

Comment: А ваши два экземпляра класса Session, 1-ый из которых создается на 2-ом скриншоте, а 2-ой из которых используется в качестве аргумента на 1-ом скриншоте, точно имеют одинковые хэшкоды? Есть подозрение, что это два разных объекта

Comment: equals и hashCodeметоды есть!

Comment: до этого были созданы user и role! Role есть поле в User! беру id role и кладу в user - все работает!

Answer (score 0):

подозреваю, что beanMapper не умеет мапить FilmDto в Film итд автоматически. не понятно какой именно это маппер, но как правило это решается аннотированием, кастомизацией или конфигурацией.

---

см [Dozer simple property mapping](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/simpleproperty.html)

> Matching field names are automatically handled by Dozer.
>
> Properties that are of the same name do not need to be specified in the mapping xml file.

т.е. если имена полей не совпадают, автоматически они мапиться не будут, их придется сконфигурить или аннотировать соотвественно, чтобы дозер "знал", что с чем мапить.

Comment: beanMapper других маппит!!! есть еще user, role!!! и при создании filmDto все ок!

Comment: хорошо, а можно больше инфы - что за маппер, какой орм?

Comment: beanMapper класс добавил в код вопроса!

Comment: до этого были созданы user и role! Role есть поле в User! беру id role и кладу в user - все работает!

Comment: а можете добавить еще и работающие классы для сравнения? я давно с дозером не работал, но как то я все еще сомневаюсь, что он умеет автоматом мапить поля разного типа с разными именами: filmDto -> film

Comment: добавил user и role

Comment: спасибо. вот в UserDto поле называется role, а не roleDto, поэтому дозер смог его замапить. попробуйте убрать суффикс Dto из названий полей.

Comment: УУУУххх!! спасибо огромное!!! помогло!!! но расскажите пожалуйста подробнее!! ведь это только имя переменной как она влияла??? где она прописывалась??